# Extracting Username and Password from raw URL

Tags: c#, url, query-string

I have a webservice that is accepting a string parameter. the parameter will always be a raw url. The user send me a raw url with the username, requestid, the option yes or no. For example:

```
http://bookReport/request.aspx?user=abc&password=password&request=1&option=yes
```

I am creating a web request and passing the url as shown below.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
var user = request.RequestUri.Query.ToString();
string[] p = Regex.Split(user, "password=");
string[] password = Regex.Split(p[1], "&request=");
```

How do I get the username, password, request, and option without having use the Regex.Split method?

Comment: @Bartdude I am thinking using the query string is easier. In addition, there could be a lot more information coming through the url. I am trying to cut down on doing so many Regex.Split.

Comment: Of course using querystring is easier... I actually thought this URL was already one of the querystring parameters. Why not use querystring then ? This is the purpose of this object...

Comment: Are you _creating_ a request or _responding_ to a request?

Comment: I am responding to the request. The person call the method AuthenticateUser and pass the url as a parameter. When I receive the url, it is a raw url that I have to extract the username, password, request, and option out of it. Then, I have to authenticate the user using that extracted information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several people have suggested you can access the querystring via the Request object's QueryString indexer. That indexer appears in System.**Web**.HttpRequest, and the object in question is System.**Net**.HttpWebRequest. They are very different things. The HttpUtility class will parse the parameters out of the querystring for you:

```
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://bookReport/request.aspx?user=abc&password=password&request=1&option=yes");        
    var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
```

[.Net Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LqdBDM)

Answer (score 1):

```
string userName = request.QueryString["user"];
string password = request.QueryString["password"];
```

Comment: I tried request.QueryString["user"], and it was null.

Comment: I think your entire code must be replaced by 

string userName = Request.QueryString["user"];
string password = Request.QueryString["password"];

Answer (score 1):

You can access the query string variables using Request.QueryString function as below

```
    string userName = Request.QueryString["user"];
    string password = Request.QueryString["password"];
    string request = Request.QueryString["request"];
    string option = Request.QueryString["option"];
```

By looking at your code, just got another approach for retrieving the query string values from a string. You can use the following code

```
            Uri uri = new Uri(url);
            var values= HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
            string userName = values["user"];
            string password = values["password"];
            string request = values["request"];
            string option = values["option"];
```

Comment: I tried it, and it was null.
string[] p = Regex.Split(user, "password=");
string username = Request.QueryString["user"]; //It returns null

Comment: I did Request.QueryString["user"]; it was null. I cannot do request.QueryString["user"] because I don't think QueryString is a member of HttpWebRequest.

Comment: try the second approach